# Using Banach's Fixed Point Theorem to show existence and uniqueness of global critical points of perturbations of quadratic functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I have a question regarding the existence of a global critical point for perturbations of quadratic functions, which is motivated by the study of Quantum Field Theories in dimension $d=0$. Consider the following function in one variable
$$
S(x) = \frac{\alpha}{2} x^2 - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda_k}{k!} x^k,
$$
where $\alpha > 0$ and $\lambda_k > 0$ for all $k \geq 1$. The goal is to show that for sufficiently small $\lambda_k$, this function has a unique critical point $x_0$ within a small box $B$ around $0$. So one can consider the equation $S’(x) = 0$, defining such critical point $x_0$. This equation can be written as $x = T(x)$, where
$$
T(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\alpha^{-1} \lambda_k}{(k-1)!} x^{k-1}
$$
At first glance, one might be inclined to apply Banach's Fixed Point Theorem to establish the existence and uniqueness of a fixed point for the equation $x = T(x)$. This would imply that $x_0 = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} T^{N}(x)$. Page 14 of Etingof’s [“Mathematical ideas and notions of Quantum Field Theory”](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Elinlin/2017Spring_290/ETI.pdf) touches upon this idea (albeit in a more general setting) without providing a thorough explanation. Etingof claims that, in the sense of a "power series norm", $T$ is a contracting mapping. However, I have been struggling to make sense of this statement. The question is: What precisely does the term "power series norm" refer to? Alternatively, which specific Banach space norm should be considered to make this statement accurate?

Answer (score 1):

I'm unfamiliar with Etingof's formalism, all I'm going to prove is that, for sufficiently small $\lambda_k$, you can indeed use Banach's fixed point theorem to get a unique fixed point. As such, my hypotheses may be less than optimal for the context this is from.

Since the points are just real numbers, we're going to use the usual $|\cdot|$ absolute value norm. To apply Banach's fixed point theorem, we need a closed and bounded subset $B\subset\mathbb{R}$ such that $T(B)\subset B$. Choosing $B:=[-1,1]$, we get for all $x\in B$:
$$
|T(x)|
\leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\alpha^{-1} \lambda_k}{(k-1)!}|x|^{k-1}
\leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\alpha^{-1} \lambda_k}{(k-1)!}.
$$
Therefore, if the $\lambda_k$ are small enough so that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\alpha^{-1} \lambda_k}{(k-1)!}\leq 1$, we have $T(B)\subset B$.

Now we need $q\in(0,1)$ such that $|T(x)-T(y)|\leq q|x-y|$. Since $x\mapsto x^k$ is $k$-Lipschitz, we have :
$$
|T(x)-T(y)| 
\leq \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{\alpha^{-1} \lambda_k}{(k-1)!}|x^{k-1}-y^{k-1}|
\leq \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{\alpha^{-1} \lambda_k}{(k-2)!}|x-y|,
$$
and we can apply the theorem and get a unique fixed point in $[-1,1]$ if the $\lambda_k$ are small enough to also have $\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{\alpha^{-1} \lambda_k}{(k-2)!} < 1$.

NB: I chose $B=[-1,1]$ almost arbitrarily, this works with $B=[-R,R]$ for any $R$. The only difference is that the bounds on $\lambda_k$ would get stronger for bigger $R$, and weaker for smaller $R$.

NB 2: I don't know if this useful, but this would also work for any arbitrary $\lambda_1>0$, the appropriate subset would just be centered around $T(0)=\alpha^{-1}\lambda_1$: $B=[\frac{\lambda_1}{\alpha}-R\, ,\ \frac{\lambda_1}{\alpha}+R]$.

Comment: I appreciate your response greatly. It certainly fulfills the purpose. However, I'm still puzzled about the meaning of "power series norm" as mentioned by Etingof.

Comment: Honestly I am too. It's possible I just haven't encountered what they're talking about, but to me "power series" would imply it's a norm of functions, yet the points are in Euclidian space.